# Android Ksoap2 not able to retrieve the Data in the 4th Activity but able to fetch the data in the begining activity

Tags: android, thread-safety, android-ksoap2

I have written an app which fetches data from a server. I am not able fetch the data in my 4 activity of my app. And I have written a separate app where it fetches and displays the data in first activity, but when integrated with my app it force closes my app ,i want to display the data in 4th Activity , i am using 2.2 Android with ksoap 2.5.4.  I will post my code and the LogCat details.

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.EditText;


public class PatientUpdate extends Activity 
{
private static String SOAP_ACTION ="http://Something.com/GetPatientByID";
private static String NAMESPACE ="http://Something.com/";
private static String METHOD_NAME ="GetPatientByID";
private static String URL ="http://Something/service1.asmx";

EditText patname;
EditText dob;
EditText category;
EditText gender;
EditText addressline1;
EditText addressline2;
EditText addressline3;
EditText addressline4;
EditText phoneno;
EditText mobileno;
EditText RegistrationDate;
EditText validitydate;
EditText monthlyincome;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.updatepatient);

    patname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpatname);
    dob = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etpatdob);
    category = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etcategory);
    gender = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etgender);
    addressline1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaddline1);
    addressline2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaddline2);
    addressline3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaddline3);
    addressline4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etaddline4);
    phoneno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etphno);
    mobileno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etmobileno);
    RegistrationDate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etregister);
    validitydate = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etvalidity);
    monthlyincome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etmoninc);


  //Initialize soap request + add parameters
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
    String date1="0019670";
    request.addProperty("patientID",date1);
    System.out.println("dfdjssf");


    // to receive the data from web service
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;//if the data is coming from .net service set it true
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

 // Make the soap call.
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    System.out.println("dfdjssf");
    try {

        //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        System.out.println("dfdjssf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    }

    // Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.parsethe data here     
    Object result;
    try {
        result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();
        Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(result));

        //String Patientid=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(0).toString();

        //for salvation and name
        String Salvation=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(1).toString();
        String Name=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(2).toString();
        patname.setText(Salvation+"."+Name);

        //for DOB
        String Dob=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(3).toString();
        dob.setText(Dob);

        //for Gender
        String Gender=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(4).toString();
        gender.setText(Gender);

        //String bloodgroup=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(5).toString();
        //String wardno=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(6).toString();
        //String maritalstatus=((SoapObject)     result).getProperty(7).toString();

        //Address  line 1 2 3 4
        String addline1=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(9).toString();
        addressline1.setText(addline1);

        String addline2=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(10).toString();
        addressline2.setText(addline2);

        String addline3=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(11).toString();
        addressline3.setText(addline3);

        String addline4=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(12).toString();
        addressline3.setText(addline4);

        //for mobile and phone no
        String phno=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(15).toString();
        phoneno.setText(phno);

        String mobno=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(16).toString();
        mobileno.setText(mobno);

        //for category validity registration and monthly income
        String categ=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(22).toString();
        category.setText(categ);

        String regdate=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(23).toString();
        RegistrationDate.setText(regdate);

        String valid=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(24).toString();
        validitydate.setText(valid);

        String montinc=((SoapObject) result).getProperty(27).toString();
        monthlyincome.setText(montinc);


        Log.v("TAG", ((SoapObject) result).getProperty(0).toString());


    } 
    catch (SoapFault e) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Log.v("TAG", String.valueOf(result));
   // SoapPrimitive result = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
   // String strRes = result.toString();


    //if(result != null)
    //{



}
}
```

The output is

```
10-24 10:30:04.766: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Starting activity: Intent { cmp=com.demo.patient/.PatientUpdate }
10-24 10:30:05.004: INFO/System.out(436): dfdjssf
10-24 10:30:05.045: INFO/System.out(436): dfdjssf
10-24 10:30:05.074: WARN/System.err(436): java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
10-24 10:30:05.084: WARN/System.err(436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocketImpl(Native Method)
10-24 10:30:05.084: WARN/System.err(436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.createStreamSocket(OSNetworkSystem.java:186)
10-24 10:30:05.084: WARN/System.err(436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.create(PlainSocketImpl.java:265)
10-24 10:30:05.095: WARN/System.err(436):     at java.net.Socket.checkClosedAndCreate(Socket.java:873)
10-24 10:30:05.095: WARN/System.err(436):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:1020)
10-24 10:30:05.095: WARN/System.err(436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:62)
10-24 10:30:05.105: WARN/System.err(436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:88)
10-24 10:30:05.105: WARN/System.err(436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getHTTPConnection(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:927)
10-24 10:30:05.105: WARN/System.err(436):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.internal.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:909)
10-24 10:30:05.105: WARN/System.err(436):     at org.ksoap2.transport.ServiceConnectionSE.connect(ServiceConnectionSE.java:75)
10-24 10:30:05.114: WARN/System.err(436):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:136)
10-24 10:30:05.114: WARN/System.err(436):     at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:90)
10-24 10:30:05.124: WARN/System.err(436):     at com.demo.patient.PatientUpdate.onCreate(PatientUpdate.java:77)
10-24 10:30:05.124: WARN/System.err(436):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-24 10:30:05.124: WARN/System.err(436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-24 10:30:05.124: WARN/System.err(436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-24 10:30:05.136: WARN/System.err(436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-24 10:30:05.136: WARN/System.err(436):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-24 10:30:05.136: WARN/System.err(436):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 10:30:05.146: WARN/System.err(436):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-24 10:30:05.146: WARN/System.err(436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-24 10:30:05.146: WARN/System.err(436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 10:30:05.155: WARN/System.err(436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-24 10:30:05.155: WARN/System.err(436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-24 10:30:05.165: WARN/System.err(436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-24 10:30:05.165: WARN/System.err(436):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 10:30:05.174: DEBUG/AndroidRuntime(436): Shutting down VM
10-24 10:30:05.174: WARN/dalvikvm(436): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.demo.patient/com.demo.patient.PatientUpdate}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope.getResponse(SoapSerializationEnvelope.java:552)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at com.demo.patient.PatientUpdate.onCreate(PatientUpdate.java:86)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
10-24 10:30:05.195: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(436):     ... 11 more
10-24 10:30:05.215: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.demo.patient/.PatientUpdate
10-24 10:30:05.225: WARN/ActivityManager(59):   Force finishing activity com.demo.patient/.Login
10-24 10:30:05.766: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{450e4258 com.demo.patient/.PatientUpdate}
10-24 10:30:14.781: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Launch timeout has expired, giving up wake lock!
10-24 10:30:15.866: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity idle timeout for HistoryRecord{45002c48 com.demo.patient/.MyApp}
10-24 10:30:21.060: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{450bab00 com.demo.patient/.Login}
10-24 10:30:21.060: WARN/ActivityManager(59): Activity destroy timeout for HistoryRecord{450e4258 com.demo.patient/.PatientUpdate}
10-24 10:30:27.940: DEBUG/SntpClient(59): request time failed: java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol
```

Comment: Should i create any threads for this.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure all arguments are set ?

If i see right, you just have two of your debug right? It means it fails here :

```
    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
```

can you give your soap WS real url ?